# Howto use Twitter-OAuth-iPhone with iOS5 and ARC

Tags: twitter, oauth, ios5

I am trying to use Ben Gottliebs Twitter-OAuth-iPhone within an iOS5 app that uses ARC. 
I already flagged the files with -fno-objc-arc. But now I get a lot of errors. I don't know where to start. Without ARC the framework seems to work just fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: it seems that is has something to do with SecKeychainItemRef
I can not find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675522/how-to-use-mgtwitterengine-for-iphone

Comment: Have you solved this problem. Can you share your solution ?

Comment: @Chrizzz, can u help me.... i also stuck same problem last 3-4 days..now i realize i wasting a lot of time in it.. Do u have any compatible sample code in which twitter will supporting both versions iOS 4 and iOS 5?

Comment: @iHungry I am sorry. But fortunately, according to current stats, already 80% of the users have iOS5

Answer (score 6):

I hope is not considered bad etiquette to recommend my own project, but I believe it's relevant to this question, so...

I just published a new OAuth library to GitHub that's fully ARC compatible. It comes with a working demo that implements the whole Twitter OAuth flow and allows you to post a tweet. You can find it here: [RSOAuthEngine](https://github.com/rsieiro/RSOAuthEngine).

Comment: I tried running this application, but it didn't work. First it said that `<AppKit/AppKit.h>` is not available and after adding it says `<Foundation/NSGeometry.h>' missing. What should i do ?

Comment: @Illep I believe this is related to a wrong compiler directive in MKNetworkKit. I'm going to double check it and create a new issue if that's the case, but for now, if you're compiling only for iOS, remove the files "NSAlert+MKNetworkKitAdditions.*" from your project and it should work.

Comment: Instead of calling a xib file (after clicking on tweet bar button), is there any way i could add the content of the xib file programatically ? (as in write code to initialize the webview, label etc) ?

`- (void)twitterEngine:(RSTwitterEngine *)engine needsToOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self.webView = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    
    [self presentModalViewController:self.webView animated:YES];
}`

ViewDidLoad is called after initWithURL is called, so where should i create the content of the xib (label, webview etc) programatically ?

Comment: I have integrated twitter successively and i could also tweet with it. I need to know how could i logout from the twitter account ? I can't find a way to log out, so could you tell me how can i do it ?

Comment: @Illep in the demo app, just slide your finger through the black bar and it will log you off. But that's just a demo of how to implement it, you can do it however you want :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using the official Twitter API that's available with iOS 5. Here's a post on how to use it: http://www.peterfriese.de/the-accounts-and-twitter-framework-on-ios-5/

Comment: Sure, thats an option. But It gives me less flexibility. Like sending a tweet in the background. And it is not support for iOS4 devices although i wrote my code with ARC

Answer (score 0):

You could just tell the compiler not to use ARC on the files included in that library.

[ios5 ARC what is the compiler flag to exclude a file from ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040629/ios5-arc-what-is-the-compiler-flag-to-exclude-a-file-from-arc)