# ios5 ARC what is the compiler flag to exclude a file from ARC?

Tags: compiler-construction, ios5, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

**Can anyone help me remember what was the flag to tell the XCode to not use ARC for some file?** I had several files in my project marked as such... Until I added another file and decided to convert that one to ARC. Sounds easy, right? I expected that I would be able to simply check a file that I want and let the XCode do it's magic. Well, not so easy, during pre-check it stripped all -Noarc flags from the files and now I need to manually re- apply the flag to several files.

the moral of this story is: **once your project is in ARC and you have some files marked as no ARC, do not re-run the convert to ARC tool from Refactor>Convert to ARC.** It will not restore your settings even if pre-check fails.

Comment: @NJones: well, it's that one that pops up on Google for the "exclude file arc" keywords :)

Comment: @NJones If it's been asked "so many times"... your post would fall on _far-less-aggravated-ears_, had you bothered to provide a **simple link** to this vaporous treasure-trove of info you refer to... vs. taking the time to post what amounts essentially a _diss, dare I say a poopoo_.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I found the answer: to exclude the file from ARC, use the **-fno-objc-arc** flag in build phases>compile sources

Comment: Hey, I wanna add, that if you want to add a compiler flag to multiple files in xcode, shift-select multiple files and press enter, and then paste, enter again. Double-clicking doesn't work for multiple selection.

Answer (score 2):

> the moral of this story is: once your project is in ARC and you have some files marked as no ARC, do not re-run the convert to ARC tool from Refactor>Convert to ARC. It will not restore your settings even if pre-check fails.

You can restore your settings for excluded files by removing references on them and then readd  to project back