# FBConnect and ARC on iOS5

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, fbconnect

I'm trying to integrate a like button in my iPhone application. Beyond the other issues, with respect to the FBConnect, I am also facing the incompatibility between FBConnect and ARC (91 build errors). Did anyone have tried to play with FBConnect on iOS 5?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for answering my question..

FB proposes to build the SDK as static library and import it to your project in that way (of course in case you are using ARC).

```
% ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

Thank you

Comment: you have to add also the header files!

Answer (score 1):

You can flag the FB files so they do not use arc, that will eliminate the errors.

See Here: 
[ios5 ARC what is the compiler flag to exclude a file from ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040629/ios5-arc-what-is-the-compiler-flag-to-exclude-a-file-from-arc)

Comment: specificly the answer to exclude the file from ARC, use the -fno-objc-arc flag in build phases>compile sources