# Linking issue using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, asihttprequest

I am developing an iPhone application (ios 5) and I am trying to use ASIHTTPRequest to facilitate my async requests. I cannot get my project to build after following the instructions exactly how they are written on the project [site.](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)

It seems I cannot link to this lib correctly

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIFormDataRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in CreateUserViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This project is using ARC perhaps that's the issue? Has anyone run into this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps you are missing a required framework.I used to get suck kind of errors when forgetting to include a framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is due to your project using ARC. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040629/ios5-arc-what-is-the-compiler-flag-to-exclude-a-file-from-arc) to exclude the library files from ARC. And it should look like something like this when you are done:

[image]

Comment: Yes that was it. I also had to add the source files to 'Compile Sources'. I would have expected xCode to do this. Anyways.. this was the solution. Thanks!