# How To Clear Cache Memory When New ViewController Call In IOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, memory, ios7

I use NSURLConnection to send request on server NSURLConnection increase cache memory and application crash due to low memory.
I use this code for clearing Cache:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

But in iOS 7 this code doesn't work any more. Does anyone have any idea how to clear cache memory ?

Comment: you can convert your code to arc by clicking edit->refractor->convert to arc  in xcode.then try with the same code.

Comment: i use third party libraries in my project which is not supported in ARC.

Comment: converting project into ARC is last option for me

Comment: You can exclude third part libraries from arc, refer to :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040629/ios5-arc-what-is-the-compiler-flag-to-exclude-a-file-from-arc

Comment: unfortunately i use this too, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: but cache memory still increase on every NSURLConnection request

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `NSURLCache` with a specific memory or disk usage limitation with `-setDiskCapacity:` or `-setMemoryCapacity:`. You can clear the cache in `UIViewController`'s `-viewWillDisappear:` or `-viewDidDisappear:`.

Comment: i use [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses] code in viewWillDisappear , viewDidDisappear and viewDidLoad but this code not working in IOS7. In IOS7 object release automatically if we use ARC but problem is i use non arc approach.

Comment: if i use NSURLCache instead of NSURLConnection then cache memory will stop increasing ???